# Installing elementary OS alongside Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu

How can I install elementary OS Loki alongside Ubuntu 16.10? I tried the ppa, but keep getting the error message: E: Unable to locate package elementary-desktop.

Help please.

-MD

Answer (score 3):

Just download iso from [elementary OS](http://elementary.io) and make bootable USB or CD.
Boot your computer from USB/CD and choose install elementary OS. 
The you'll have an option to install elementary OS alongside other systems. Choose it and the you'll have a simple hard drive manager to make some space for elementary OS.

Finally, follow installing instructions on screen. :)